# Resuming Kafka Stream from Custom Offset

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to find some way to resume the Kafka Streams from manual offset.
from finding on the Internet I didn't find any answer that says it can.

is there any way? or have to go back to low-level consumers API :\

Answer (score 0):

In order for your kafka streams application to resume from a specific offset, you should reset offset for its consume group. The consumer group of your application has the same name as `application.id` configuration.

First, make sure that your consumer has no active members for a safe offset reset:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <your bootstrap server> --group <your consumer group> --describe
```

and thenn to reset offsets, you can use this command:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <your bootstrap server> --group <your consumer group> --reset-offsets --to-offset <a specific offset> --topic <topic in question> --execute
```

Keep in mind that offsets only have meaning in relation to each others within a single partition for a single consumer group, so this command would reset the offset of all partitions of the topic.